# Theme problems Themes & Login screen on xfce

Tags: linux, gnome, themes, linux-mint, xfce

I'm using Linux Mint Debian 201109 (Xfce) version.
I added debian repositories to apt and updated whole system.
And now I have a problems with styles/themes on some applications(they use standart xfce(gnome?)): NetworkManager, Synaptic, LoginScreen

Also the login screen uses the same theme, but most of my applications looks like(e.g. they are using my choosed theme): Mixer, Firefox and others...

The I've installed GDM3Settings from deb package from github but I can't run the application from menu.
Here is the ouput from `$sudo sudo gdm3setup.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdm3setup.py", line 697, in <module>
    MainWindow().show_all()
  File "/usr/bin/gdm3setup.py", line 405, in __init__
    self.get_gdm()
  File "/usr/bin/gdm3setup.py", line 474, in get_gdm
    self.USER_LIST = str_to_bool(get_setting("USER_LIST",settings))
  File "/usr/bin/gdm3setup.py", line 669, in get_setting
    return value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
```

So, how can I change styles on applications which are using wrong theme, and how I can customize login screen?

Comment: Remember that your applications may use different frameworks for GUI e.g. `qt` or `gtk`.

Comment: Ok, but as I know xfce and gnome use gtk, not qt. I mean I have application which are using gtk and they looks good... So I do not think this is the problem of difference between gtk/qt styling.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the problem of using theme. My installed theme uses GTK2, but for example NetworkManager uses GTK3 themes.

Problem can be solved by removing `gdm3`(GDM3)

```
sudo apt-get remove gdm3
```

And installing `gdm`(GDM2)

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Now GTK 2.x can be used for `xfce` and `gdm`